# MySQL Wildcard for "=" - is there one

Tags: mysql, wildcard

So,

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%'
```

will return everything. Is there a wildcard for the query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = '*'
```

Clearly `*` doesn't work, I just put it there to indicate where I'd like a wildcard. The column I'm selecting from contains an integer between 1 and 12, and I want to be able to select either all records with a particular number, or all records with a wildcard.

Thanks,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

LIKE is basically the same as =, except LIKE lets you use wildcards.

These two queries will return the same results:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE 'xyz';
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col='xyz';
```

Without a '%' in the LIKE query, it is effectively the same as '='.

If you're doing a selection on an integer column, you should consider using the IN() or BETWEEN operators.  It sounds like you have two separate conditions that should be handled in your code however, rather than in the query, as your conditions dictate that you need at least two different kinds of queries.

Edit:  I should clarify that LIKE and = are similar only in normal, humdrum string comparison usage.  You should check the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) for specifics on how it works, as there are situations where it's not the same (such as language sets).

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. Will handle it in code and change the query to include that particular WHERE clause if and when it's needed.

Comment: Does MySQL support BETWEEN? I thought that was just TSQL

Comment: @Joe: BETWEEN is standard SQL.  I've never met any system supporting SQL that doesn't support BETWEEN.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to select everything, why are you attaching the WHERE clause at all? Just leave it off conditionally instead of putting a wildcard into it.

Comment: I was thinking that, then I thought, no, that's nonsensical, he must just be using the wildcard as an example and really he would anchor text on one or both sides of it.  Then I reread the question in detail and no, you're right, he just needs to leave off the WHERE for his application.

Comment: Dan, you know that the WHERE part is optional, right? If you leave it off, then you'll select every row.

Comment: On the contrary, it's easier to have an optional argument if you do it this way. You can prepare a single statement and, if there are no constraints required, simply pass `%` to `execute()` in the case of PDO. If there are constraints, it works just the same as an =.  This made my code so much cleaner because as of php7, I can do this `$stmt->execute([$args['class'] ?? '%']);` instead of preparing two separate big 'ole queries!

Answer (score 7):

The reason for using LIKE is because the = does not offer wildcard support. Otherwise there would be no reason for LIKE

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col RLIKE '.*'
```

i.e. regular-expression LIKE.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of that nice MySQL operator.

RLIKE aka REGEXP is worth knowing: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query is parameter driven a case statement is probably appropriate

```
select * from mytable
where col like case when @myvariable is null then % else myvariable end
```

Where `@myvariable` is either null if you dont want a value otherwise it would use the integer value you pass in.

Answer (score 0):

zombat's answer is great, but I only noticed in his answer that you are selecting integers. He mentioned IN() and BETWEEN(). Here's examples using those syntaxes, as well as some other options you have for an integer field.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = 1;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col BETWEEN 1 AND 12;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col BETWEEN 6 AND 12;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col <= 6;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col < 6;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col >= 6;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col > 6;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col <> 6;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col IN (1,2,5,6,10);
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col NOT IN (1,2,5,6,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered such a case while building a stored procedure for a report
Following is my solution, hope this is what you had in mind :)

```
set @p = "ALL";
```

Query:

```
select * from fact_orders
where
dim_country_id = if(@p is null or @p="ALL", dim_country_id, @p)
limit 10
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your values are in the the range (1,12) then:

select * from table where col>=5 and col<=5;  //this is equal to col=5

select * from table where col>=0 and col<=12; //this is equal to col=any value

The same line can produce both effects by choosing the 2 parameters appropriately.
I faced a similar problem when I needed a single prepared statement which should work with 2 different ways , either checking for a particular value in a column or ignoring that column completely.