# How to change SQL query in PHP in relation to what drop down menus the user selects

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am currently doing a project in school which involves using a form to query a database. This form has multiple drop down menus and I am unsure on how to query the database if the user does not fill out all of the drop down menus. For example if the user only wants to search for a certain job type and does not specify the industry.

INDEX.HTML

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="test.php" method="post">
            <select name="varjobtype">
                <option value="nullg" disabled selected hidden>Job Type</option>
                <option value="Part Time">Part Time</option>
                <option value="Full Time">Full Time</option> 
                <option value="Contract">Contract</option>
                <option value="Temporary">Temporary</option>
            </select>
            <select name="varindustry">
                <option value="null" disabled selected hidden>Industry</option>
                <option value="Accommodation and Food Services">Accommodation and Food Services</option>
                <option value="Retail">Retail</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

TEST.PHP

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
        $jobtype = $_POST['varjobtype'];
        $industry = $_POST['varindustry'];

        $sql = "SELECT `Job ID`, Name, Employer FROM JobListings WHERE `Job Type`  = '$jobtype' AND `Industry` = '$industry' ";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>
                <div id="<? echo $row['Job ID']; ?>" class="box">
                <?
             echo "Job ID: " . $row["Job ID"]. "<br>";     
                echo "Name: " . $row["Name"]. "<br>"; 
                echo "Employer: " . $row["Employer"]. "<br>";
             echo "</div>";
            }
        ?>            
        <?
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        $conn->close();
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

As of now the php outputs no results.How would you make it so even if the user selects one of the drop down menus then the SQL statement will still display the jobs. Is it possible to make it so that it displays all of the jobs if the user does not interact with any of the drop down menus?

Comment: You could try to replace the default selected field's value to '%'. Then in your query you should replace the '=' in the WHERE clause to 'LIKE'. The default value will act as a wildcard then. http://stackoverflow.com/a/804405/5884874

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$jobtype = isset($_POST['varjobtype']) ? $_POST['varjobtype'] : '';
$industry = isset($_POST['varindustry']) ? $_POST['varindustry'] :'';

$sql = "SELECT `Job ID`, Name, Employer FROM JobListings";

$where = array();

if ($jobtype) $where[] = "`Job Type`  = '".$jobtype."'";

if ($industry ) $where[] = "`Industry` = '".$industry."'";

if (!empty($where)) {
     $sql .= " where " . implode (" and ",$where);
}

$result = $conn->query($sql);
...
```

Comment: Tip: In PHP 7 the top two lines of code can be cleaned up with the [null coalescence operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).

Comment: This error "  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'  " appears for line 12?

Comment: @matthew6543 edideted: if (!empty($where)) {

Comment: You can't just `implode` on raw variables and inject those into the query. This creates a massive [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: the question was not about sql injection, implode or what he wrote ($sql = "SELECT `Job ID`, Name, Employer FROM JobListings WHERE `Job Type`  = '$jobtype' AND `Industry` = '$industry' ";) is same thing can not prevent sql injection. There is other threads which talk about this for example [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)