# node.js wildcard string into mysql query

Tags: mysql, node.js, wildcard

I'm currently working on a Node.js project and I'm struggling with the wildcard in my mysql query. Here's the code:

```
exports.getList = function (shop, callback) {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM chain.shop WHERE shopName = ? AND shopPlace = ?;";

    if (shop.shopName == null)
        shop.shopName = "*";
    if (shop.shopPlace == null)
        shop.shopPlace = "*";

    conn.query(sql, [shop.shopName, shop.shopPlace], function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;

        callback(result);
        console.log(this.sql); // shows exectued query
    });
}
```

Let's say the shopPlace is null, the executed query will be something like

`"SELECT * FROM chain.shop WHERE shopName = 'myShop' AND shopPlace = '*';"`

This delivers no results as it can't find a shopPlace named `'*'`. I was wondering how to use the * as a wildcard in this example, rather than a string with single quotes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Wildcard for "=" - is there one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804381/mysql-wildcard-for-is-there-one)

Comment: Using LIKE did the job. Thanks!

Comment: Use LIKE clause: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804381/mysql-wildcard-for-is-there-one